# Why was the title of Rivers of London changed to Midnight Riot?

Tags: title-explanation, rivers-of-london

The novel [*Rivers of London*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivers_of_London_(novel)), originally published in Britain, was published in the US under the title *Midnight Riot*.

**Why was the title changed for the US audience?**

(Presumably it can't be [because](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/106045/31394) "rivers" or "London" would be considered too hard or unfamiliar for American readers.)

Comment: Author claims not to know; https://mobile.twitter.com/Silver_Rumbelle/status/407577442543751169

Comment: Probably because "Rivers of London" sounds like a sedate travel guide.

Comment: [Too British](https://temporarilysignificant.blogspot.com/search?q=Midnight+Riot%5D) seems to be a common complaint. The title change might have come from the publisher trying to get people who might think that to buy the book anyway.

Comment: @Jontia: rumours of a sequel novel entitled _Trousers of Autumn_ have yet to be confirmed.